# Angular highlight the whole word when clicked and show it in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to highlight the whole word when i click on it and save it to some variable so I can do something with it. I don't know where to begin, because I'm new to angular.

Comment: which word ? where? code?

Comment: Any word in my website. Lets say in a div tag.

Comment: trt this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/8y952mc4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt using exclusively Angular

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope' , function($scope) {

  var text = "a bit of text here";

  $scope.textArray= text.split(" ");

  $scope.print = function(t){
    // this function fetches the word, you can do anything with variable `t`
    console.log(t); // for instance I output it in the console
  }

  
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <p>
    <span ng-repeat="t in textArray" ng-click="print(t)">{{t}} </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats all i needed!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var clickedWord;
$(".clickable").click(function(e) {
  s = window.getSelection();
  var range = s.getRangeAt(0);
  var node = s.anchorNode;
  while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') != 0) {
    range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));
  }
  range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);
  do {
    range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);
  } while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') == -1 && range.toString().trim() != '');
  var str = range.toString().trim();
  console.log(str);
  clickedWord = str;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="clickable">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris rutrum ante nunc. Proin sit amet sem purus. Aliquam malesuada egestas metus, vel ornare purus sollicitudin at. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer porta turpis
  ut mi pharetra rhoncus. Ut accumsan, leo quis hendrerit luctus, purus nunc suscipit libero, sit amet lacinia turpis neque gravida sapien. Nulla facilisis neque sit amet lacus ornare consectetur non ac massa. In purus quam, imperdiet eget tempor eu,
  consectetur eget turpis. Curabitur mauris neque, venenatis a sollicitudin consectetur, hendrerit in arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras iaculis, est eu pulvinar suscipit, nisl neque
  commodo dui, eu bibendum velit leo vel tortor. Nulla eget mauris et libero gravida malesuada. Sed at massa gravida diam rhoncus condimentum. Duis nulla turpis, faucibus vel luctus et, gravida condimentum ante. Integer tincidunt lacus in ante pharetra
  vitae auctor ipsum malesuada. Phasellus nunc mauris, ultrices quis ultrices a, ultricies fermentum eros. Curabitur non diam et tellus bibendum pellentesque ac vel eros. Nullam varius turpis non est viverra viverra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit. Quisque consectetur, tortor eget viverra laoreet, eros ante lobortis massa, eu molestie nisl mi non urna. Fusce vehicula tincidunt porta. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
  Fusce ac arcu faucibus tellus eleifend blandit. Donec quis massa odio, in hendrerit lacus. Proin a dolor massa. Aenean urna nunc, mattis vel euismod sit amet, accumsan quis elit. Fusce sit amet odio diam. Curabitur ipsum enim, eleifend et aliquam non,
  laoreet ac est. Maecenas cursus mauris eu sapien consequat consequat. Curabitur commodo euismod arcu non condimentum. Proin quis libero vitae arcu pretium porttitor. Ut sapien tellus, fermentum sit amet scelerisq tortor. Nunc convallis varius lacinia. Donec leo leo, suscipit et porttitor nec, vulputate a nulla. Morbi in ullamcorper orci. Nam sed est ut enim tincidunt rhoncus at vitae neque. Morbi dapibus, duis eros. Nunc porttitor gravida pharetra. Curabitur eu dui eget sapien faucibus luctus. Praesent
  vel lectus est, pellentesque elementum felis. Donec a varius eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus non nulla elit, non sollicitudin quam. Proin id tempus mauris. Suspendisse lorem augue,
  mattis elementum blandit quis, dapibus sit amet ante. Pellentesque in turpis non ante aliquam tincidunt sed porttitor enim. Proin bibendum ornare ullamcorper. Aenean egestas elit at turpis sollicitudin laoreet. Maecenas varius lacus vitae urna dictum
  consectetur. Quisque et justo leo, eu consequat nibh. Donec nunc ante, vehicula vel pharetra id, tincidunt in ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam tincidunt eros nunc. Nulla facilisi.
  Nullam non suscipit dolor. Maecenas lobortis accumsan nibh sollicitudin hendrerit. Phasellus arcu sapien, tincidunt eu convallis id, ultricies id leo. Phasellus sed risus eu nunc mattis lobortis a vel sapien. Phasellus et nulla ligula. Morbi nec faucibus
  tortor. Aliquam sem turpis, molestie non tincidunt vel, rhoncus vitae enim. Nullam volutpat nibh non augue iaculis dignissim. Sed aliquam ullamcorper lacus id congue. Maecenas feugiat ligula nec orci semper blandit volutpat quam egestas. Pellentesque
  quam est, vulputate ac luctus in, placerat vitae odio. Sed accumsan rutrum nibh vel faucibus. Mauris pellentesque ligula sed nulla aliquet a venenatis arcu congue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  Pellentesque feugiat, nisl in ullamcorper aliquet, risus nunc lobortis quam, a pellentesque ante orci in lacus. Mauris eu nibh a ligula imperdiet malesuada et ac velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam lacinia fringilla
  nibh, non vulputate neque faucibus non. Sed luctus nunc vel nisi aliquam eleifend. Mauris non urna et purus rhoncus dignissim. Sed purus arcu, hendrerit id gravida rutrum, aliquam eu odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
  nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque dictum euismod lorem, nec auctor dui rutrum quis. Donec eget est nulla, ac tincidunt erat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec sed lectus vitae urna
  elementum accumsan vel ut sem. Aliquam a nunc est. Morbi enim nulla, blandit eget faucibus et, porttitor at leo. Fusce metus neque, condimentum sed adipiscing ac, vulputate ac augue. Mauris viverra dui eget magna eleifend quis suscipit lorem lacinia.
  In pellentesque rutrum libero. Ut velit sem, interdum non pretium ut, pulvinar nec orci. Etiam in ullamcorper orci. Phasellus adipiscing hendrerit cursus. Integer blandit velit sodales velit imperdiet molestie. Praesent consequat dictum erat, eget vestibulum
  eros eleifend id. Aenean in purus malesuada arcu accumsan porttitor at et nisi. Sed sit amet iaculis nibh. Sed convallis tincidunt nibh et malesuada. Nulla pretium luctus arcu, a malesuada est mollis nec. Maecenas faucibus semper odio, et pellentesque
  lectus sollicitudin in. Suspendisse ut mi mauris, a dapibus urna. Fusce vel turpis ut velit iaculis porttitor. Morbi at interdum tortor. Sed vulputate risus ac leo fringilla imperdiet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc vitae tortor libero. Vivamus hendrerit
  turpis nisl, a vestibulum mi. Quisque facilisis libero quis ante feugiat vel consectetur felis ornare. Mauris urna odio, pharetra ac imperdiet non, posuere vitae lacus. Donec convallis neque non magna pretium ac tristique tellus volutpat. Donec in eros
  dolor. Vestibulum elit tortor, vulputate quis dignissim eget, iaculis sit amet sem. Donec sit amet ornare nibh. Sed pellentesque tristique lacus eu adipiscing. Duis aliquam metus bibendum nunc accumsan interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
  dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque ut libero quis dolor accumsan posuere id at enim. Pellentesque ut dui eu leo ullamcorper congue. Vestibulum convallis imperdiet diam, sit amet tempus dolor dictum vulputate. Nam ac dui elit.
  Nullam bibendum lectus et sem volutpat semper laoreet ut dolor. Fusce vel augue venenatis velit dapibus rutrum vel vel nibh. Curabitur hendrerit, libero non imperdiet blandit, velit enim venenatis dui, at fermentum nunc ante at turpis. Sed tincidunt
  est non orci vehicula a faucibus turpis hendrerit. Duis viverra ipsum ac nibh suscipit non fringilla leo ornare. Cras lobortis elementum mi. Cras lobortis adipiscing nulla, egestas feugiat ligula blandit vel. Donec vitae sagittis ipsum. Aliquam tincidunt
  porttitor leo in ultrices. Duis lorem odio, vulputate id tristique in, dapibus sit amet felis. Aliquam enim arcu, laoreet porttitor dapibus vel, aliquet a velit. Pellentesque feugiat augue non purus feugiat eget porta nunc egestas. Curabitur lobortis
  euismod ipsum, eget convallis dolor blandit at. Donec quis felis lacus. Quisque condimentum varius est non gravida. Praesent vitae velit et quam bibendum hendrerit in vel quam. Cras velit ante, tempor luctus pretium in, lacinia at lectus. Proin tristique,
  eros id posuere suscipit, urna nulla faucibus justo, sed aliquet tellus urna et nulla. Morbi et sem nibh, vel cursus odio. Morbi ligula nisl, eleifend eu tincidunt in, dictum non leo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam eget lacus sit amet diam luctus commodo.
  Maecenas imperdiet, nibh ut interdum venenatis, augue leo sodales metus, id malesuada diam quam sed ipsum. Morbi vulputate urna eu nisi aliquam porta euismod vitae sapien. Quisque quam metus, elementum in hendrerit eget, dignissim non dolor. Duis tristique,
  lacus sed facilisis tempus, tellus quam vulputate felis, in rhoncus mauris augue ut ligula. Sed dictum semper congue. In hendrerit dictum odio, a molestie erat egestas eu. In convallis semper ante, vestibulum condimentum orci bibendum non. Nam dictum
</p>
```